# Need help in Navigation Drawer Page Sliding Tab Strip Android

Tags: android, android-fragments, pagerslidingtabstrip

I have downloaded `Navigation Drawer Page Sliding Tab Strip` for Slider and Tab Menus. It is working fine.

Source : https://github.com/Balaji-K13/Navigation-drawer-page-sliding-tab-strip

But As I have checked, When User clicks on any tab, It is showing `Textview Text like Card 1, Card 2` and so on.

Same way, If user clicks on any Slider menu, It is showing images of Planet.
But, Instead of these both, I want to open `Fragment` in `Sliding` menu click and as well as on `Tab` Click. 
It might be silly questions but I am not that much familiar with Android. Please help me regarding this.

Answer (score 7):

for the changing in tabs  you can do this , go to **`PageSlidingTabStripFragment.java`** ,              ***`getItem()`*** methode you can remove the *return* statment and you can do something like this:

```
public SherlockFragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position) {

        // Open FragmentTab1.java
        case 0:
            FragmentTab1 fragmenttab1 = new FragmentTab1();
            return fragmenttab1;

        // Open FragmentTab2.java
        case 1:
            FragmentTab2 fragmenttab2 = new FragmentTab2();
            return fragmenttab2;

        // Open FragmentTab3.java
        case 2:
            FragmentTab3 fragmenttab3 = new FragmentTab3();
            return fragmenttab3;
        }
```

which FragmentTab1 can be like this:

```
    public class FragmentTab1 extends SherlockFragment {
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragmenttab1, container, false);
            return rootView;
        }

}
```